# How to make crispy fried prawns without overcooking them?

Tags: shrimp

I fry medium prawns for 2 minutes per side on a high flame, and I think they shrink quite a lot, I tried cooking them for 2 minutes per side and 1 minute on the other on a medium flame but they didn't turn out to be crispy.

Comment: Can you clarify "crispy?"   Do you intend to coat them with some type of batter or starch so that they are actually crisp?

Comment: See also: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/116691/how-do-you-properly-and-consistently-pan-sear-shrimp?rq=1

Comment: No, just oil @moscafj

Comment: In that case, I will suggest that my linked question provides the guidance you need.

Comment: hmm, okay I'll follow those tips, makes sense, thanks.@moscafj